# How can i use @string/xyz in .java file?

Tags: java, android

I have created a 'hello world' Android project and i want to use my string in **MainActivity.java**.
In **string.xml** file i have a string named `password`

How can i *call* this string to my **MainActivity.java**?

```
<string name="password">Your password is:</string>
```

a part of **MainActivity.java**

```
    ....
    ....
    //Show password on click
    showBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //i want to use a string called from string.xml instead of hard coded
            resTXT.setText("Your password is:"+ pass);
        }
    });

   ....
   ....
```

Comment: I meant `String password = getString(R.string.password);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
final String passwordText = getString(R.string.password);

//Show password on click
showBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //i want to use a string called from string.xml instead of hard coded
        resTXT.setText(passwordText + pass);
    }
});
```

The [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) method in Context is meant to retrieve String resources from XML. Use the [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29) method, also in Context, if you want to retain any rich formatting.

Comment: good solution, thanks. but when i try only R.string.password without getString() method it it converting itself to an integer format so i cant assing it to String passwordText. Why int?

Comment: @hakiko The getString method takes an int as an argument. When you compile your app, android compresses all XML resource into Binary format, and assigns one integer ID to each string, layout, style, color, drawbable etc. You then use this int ID to reference it from within your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `R.string.password`.  Android autogenerates an R file from your resources